# Determine application home location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a program that the user must run the .exe from his/her desktop...  If they try to run it from somewhere else i would like to have the .vbs pop up file I created to show up telling them to place it on the desktop.  I have already made the program and it works fine, but people can't read the instructions, so I thought this might be a good approach.  Unfortunatley, I am having trouble with it and I am going nowhere.  If someone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you care about it being on  the desktop? Perhaps you can eliminate that dependency instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really understand why you'd want to do this but you could check in  Main to see if the app was run from the Desktop

```
static void Main()
{

  var AsmPath =System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase ) ;

   var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

  if (AsmPath == desktopPath)
  (
      MessageBox.Show ("You can only run this from the desktop");
      Application.Exit();
  )
  else 
       Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do something from the perspective of the person's Desktop (such as where to store files relative to the desktop), you can just query that location and use it as basis of any subsequent work.

```
string UserDesktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Conrad on not being sure why you want to do this. But if you are talking about putting the exe on the desktop and executing from there (as opposed to a shortcut) then you should be able to use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location and compare it to the users desktop location with System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)